# Hit Animations in Spritekit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I been playing around with xcode using swift for a while. i recently got into using Spritekit.

I wanted to experiment with animations for when the player shoots a bullet at an enemy and to show that the sprite took damage (or contacted it) it would switch the sprite image for half a second then switch back to the regular image.

I guess an example of this would be in super mario RPG, when mario hits an enemy, their eyes pop out

Is this a good way to approach the hit animation by switching the images back and forth or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching the texture would work, but give a sudden change. Animating the sprite through a short series of textures (e.g eyes beginning to pop, eyes half way popped, eyes popped) would look better and can be implemented easily using SKActions. See [Apple's Sprite Programming Guide, Changing a Sprites Texture](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW47)